# What does it mean that a graph dual is not unique, because the dual depends on the particular embedding?

Tags: graph-theory

What does it mean that a graph dual is not unique, because the dual depends on the particular embedding?

I don't get what graph embeddings are and how they're related to the uniqueness of the dual.

Particularly, is drawing the dual meant to be done in planar sense? That one considers as if the graph was projected on to a plane? So one is able to cross edges once in only a particular way, whereas in a "space" representation I don't think the embedding would matter, since one'd always draw through the edges the same way.

Comment: I think you calculate a dual (not the dual) by drawing a plane picture of a (planar) graph, then putting a dual vertex in each region. But there are different ways to draw the graph in the plane that lead to different duals. (Posted as a comment not an answer since I haven't worked out details.)

Comment: @EthanBolker That confuses the notion of the dual a bit though, doesn't it? Since there are many duals, then how do decide, which one to use?

Comment: You can't decide that in advance. "The dual" is ambinguous.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Uniqueness for a confirmation of my comment. There's an example there.

Comment: Interpret `dual` as a function of the embedded graph, or the embedding itself, not as a function of the graph.